# How to replace dynamic string?

Tags: php, regex

I have variable `$menu` type array like below:

```
$menu = array('<li class="page_item page-item-155">',
              '<li class="page_item page-item-49">',
              '<li class="page_item page-item-72">',
              '<li class="page_item page-item-18">',
              '<li class="page_item page-item-50">');
```

I want to replace the first original string

```
<li class="page_item page-item-155">'
```

to

```
<li class="current">
```

In the end of the string it can be any number, the numbers are not constant.

I think I need to use a regular expression but I don't know how to implement it.

```
$menu = str_replace($original_strs_array, $replacement_strs_array, $menu);
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using an XML parser for whatever it is you're doing?

Comment: Just replace `-X"` with `-X current"`, where `X` is current selected menu. No need to replace class names.

Comment: @glavić That should be an answer.

Comment: @deizel: I am not sure that this is what eh wants. Variable $menu is array, so does he wants to replace every value? Or just the selected $menuId ?

Comment: @glavić I presume he has the ID, so just your str_replace in a foreach? (using $id instead of X)

Comment: @deizel: That is the problem, he hasn't told what he wants exactly. And you do not need `foreach()`, because 3rd parameter in `str_replace()` will accept array.

Comment: I have answered for all 4 possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Code

#### All $menu values: replace class="*" with class="current"

```
$menuA = preg_replace('~class=".+"~', 'class="current"', $menu);
print_r($menuA);
```

#### All $menu values: add className "current" to the current class

```
$menuB = preg_replace('~class="(.+?)"~', 'class="$1 current"', $menu);
print_r($menuB);
```

#### Selected menu: replace class="*" with class="current"

```
$menuC = preg_replace('~class=".*?page-item-'.$selectedMenuId.'"~', 'class="current"', $menu);
print_r($menuC);
```

#### Selected menu: add className "current" to the current class

```
$menuD = preg_replace('~class="(.*?)page-item-('.$selectedMenuId.')"~', 'class="$1page-item-$2 current"', $menu);
print_r($menuD);
```

## Output

```
$menuA = Array
(
    [0] => <li class="current">
    [1] => <li class="current">
    [2] => <li class="current">
    [3] => <li class="current">
    [4] => <li class="current">
)
$menuB = Array
(
    [0] => <li class="page_item page-item-155 current">
    [1] => <li class="page_item page-item-49 current">
    [2] => <li class="page_item page-item-72 current">
    [3] => <li class="page_item page-item-18 current">
    [4] => <li class="page_item page-item-50 current">
)
$menuC = Array
(
    [0] => <li class="page_item page-item-155">
    [1] => <li class="page_item page-item-49">
    [2] => <li class="current">
    [3] => <li class="page_item page-item-18">
    [4] => <li class="page_item page-item-50">
)
$menuD = Array
(
    [0] => <li class="page_item page-item-155">
    [1] => <li class="page_item page-item-49">
    [2] => <li class="page_item page-item-72 current">
    [3] => <li class="page_item page-item-18">
    [4] => <li class="page_item page-item-50">
)
```

Comment: NP. Next time be more specific in the question.

Comment: if `$menu` will be string not array and I want to replace just in the first tag `li`, How can I convet it to `class="current"` ? Thanks .

Comment: Just add `1` in the 4th parameter of the `preg_replace()` function, no matter if `$menu` is string or array.

Comment: np! we are here to help ;-) and get helped ;-)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
preg_replace('/page_item page-item-\d+/','current',$menu);
```

Or this for a generic class remover/replacer:

```
preg_replace("/class\s*=\s*('|\")[^'\"]*('|\")/",'class="current"',$menu);
```

Comment: .. or just `\d+` (if you are doing a comparison with the matching number).

Comment: @deizel: he wants to replace `page_item page-item-` too

Comment: True, but there is probably no need when the extra class can just be added. :)

Comment: @deizel: Yes he can add class by Javascript and override CSS (if its needed) and forget all these. but he asked a PHP replacement question and I answered like that! ;-)